# Next n-th day of the month - excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

Let's say I wanna calculate my next paycheck date every day in excel. I get money each 5th day of the month. How can i do it?

Expected outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+IF(DAY(A2)<=5,0,1),5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
=EOMONTH(A2,-(DAY(A2)<=5))+5
```

---

***Edit***

As requested a short summary of how I got to the above:

Initially started of with thinking about checking the number of the day of the month in an IF-statement.

```
=IF(DAY(A2)<=5,A2+5-DAY(A2),EDATE(A2+5-DAY(A2),1))
```

This would check if the returned value is smaller or equal to 5. If so, then it would add the remainder of 5 minus the returned value to the current date. If false, then it would use `EDATE` to get the same date of the previous calculation in the *next* month.

Since this looked still like it had redundant parts I started looking for a different approach where I wouldn't have to do the same calculation twice. Ended up with:

```
=EOMONTH(A2,IF(DAY(A2)<=5,-1,0))+5
```

Yet, still the `IF` is redundant because I need either to get a -1 or a zero as the second argument in `EOMONTH`. Therefor we just need the expression to return `TRUE` or `FALSE` and multiply it by `-1` or rather `-`.

Comment: A shorter formula... by 2 characters! Nice.

Comment: @BigBen, it's called "Code Golf", and unnoticed I guess I'm always lurking for *shorter* =(.

Comment: Does that mean that this answer qualifies as a double birdie? ;-) Oh even better now. Yeah `EOMONTH` is the better way to go here.

Comment: It most certainly does, that is a much better approach than mine.

Comment: Well, that may be just a hole-in-one now? @BigBen

Comment: Lol. Yup. Pretty soon it'll be a *hole-in-zero*.